# SSRS 2005 Subscription changes

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, subscriptions

OK this is my question(s) and its SSRS 2005 and SQL Server 2005/2008

I had been tasked with rebuilding a dozen or so reports that our users use on their data systems.  We just build them and since every DB instance is schematically the same for all our clients, we push the reports out to their report servers for use.

So modified a great many reports, but the reports have blown away the clients subscriptions.  So every user that uses these reports, that can be a great many seeing as how everyone can have their own set of parameters, has to run the reports manually or redo their subscriptions.

My company would very much like to avoid that, but I can not figure out how to change a report, and even with the same parameter set going in as the last report, keep the subscription there.

Even when I copy the report down to their report server and replace the old with the new using same name.  The subscription is still there, but it gets modified.

1. I am looking either for a way to push down a subscription as part of the report, so that they will have minimal input to their subscriptions in order to tailor it to their needs 
   --OR ideally--
2. Upload a new version of the report to their report server and just have the subscription apply to the newest report that I have put on their server

It doesn't really matter which one but the second is best seeing as how individual users use the reports with individual names as a parameter

Many thanks in advance for anyone that can point me to the way to manage out subscriptions on my side, or enable my reports to assume the subscriptions of same named reports on their server.
--edit--
Want to put a clearer picture out there
I have a master copy of a report.  The users use the report on their own systems.
I do some heavy modifications to the master copy of the report, and upload it to their systems.  using the same name and same parameter set as the original report.
I want the subscriptions on their report server to find this report using the same name.
so XXX.report has a subscription.  I change it to XXX.report locally, and upload to their servers.  The subscriptions are not synching though.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're accessing SSRS but you can use the following webservice methods to download and upload report subscriptions

1. [ListSubscriptions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listsubscriptions.aspx)
2. [GetSubscriptionProperties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.getsubscriptionproperties.aspx)
3. [GetDataDrivenSubscriptionProperties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.getdatadrivensubscriptionproperties.aspx)
4. [DeleteSubscription](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.deletesubscription.aspx)
5. [CreateDataDrivenSubscription](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createdatadrivensubscription.aspx)
6. [CreateSubscription](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createsubscription.aspx)

Using those methods, you use **ListSubscriptions** to get a report's subcriptions. The [Subscription.IsDataDriven](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.subscription.isdatadriven.aspx) property will tell you if it's data driven or not. For data driven subscriptions, use **GetDataDrivenSubscriptionProperites** to get the subscription properties, otherwise use **GetSubscriptionProperties**. All of those classes are XML serializable so you can save them to disk out of the box using the [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

To readd the subscriptions, use **DeleteSubscription** to delete the subcriptions one by one and then **CreateSubscription** or **CreateDataDrivenSubscription** to readd the subscriptions.

This is a hack though, because you should be able to modify reports without breaking the subscriptions. You should to the following to help diagnose the issue

1. [Set SSRS logging to verbose for all components](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2146315?wa=wsignin1.0)
2. Use the click once report builder to change the title of a report and see if the subscriptions break when you click save
3. Have the SQL profiler running on the ReportServer database to see what SQL is being generated when the subscriptions break

Comment: I agree about the hack part.  The issue that is biting us, I am coming to find, is that the reports were accidentally migrated to a higher version before I joined the company and we have been rebuilding them down to the 2005 version.  So in essence they are 'new' reports, but to our users we are trying to make it appear seamless with their subscriptions moving from the old to the new.   And I access the reports through SSRS and SSMS, no web side work.

Answer (score 0):

there's a tool called Reporting Services Scripter from  Jasper Smith. I think it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to wind up doing was going back and change all the input parameters, including the sql content for the drop downs, back to what they originally were.  Then playing with the SQL for the report to accept the new(old) parameters.

Thanks for your input.  I accepted the web services answer as that is a path I will have to explore for our next update.